# New field permission during Push update

Tags: managed-package, push-upgrade, field-level-security

The question is about permission for newly added custom field in a managed package.
Consider the situation when we have a managed package (say version 1.0), and we're going to Push upgrade on customer's Org (to version 2.0 which contain **new custom field**). 
What will be **field level security setting** for this new custom field?
When we install package first time Salesforce prompts us about security settings for all the profiles. But how are they set during Push upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

An old question, but may be this Documentation here helps answer it. I stumbled upon your question and found it unanswered.

[Push Upgrades and New Components](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/push_upgrade_assigning_access.htm)

[Sample Script for Post Install for Push Upgrades](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/packagingGuide/Content/push_upgrade_post_install_script.htm)