# Keeping a ViewAllData permissionset viewing all fields

Tags: apex, unit-test, security, field-level-security, push-upgrade

I have a permissionset which I want to grant broad read-only access to nearly all fields and objects.  I've granted the permissionset the ViewAllData permission already, but [that permission does not grant field-level security](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30240/how-do-modify-all-data-and-view-all-data-affect-field-level-security-setting), only record-level security.

In order to ensure that developers don't forget to add Read permissions to new fields, there's a unit test which ensures this by leveraging `Schema.getGlobalDescribe()` and a blocklist (SObjects like `ApexTestResult` are excluded since I do NOT want to grant this user `Customize Application` permissions).

All well and good - developers are fine with this, and so is the org.  I even have a script that inserts/removes prod-only object permissions on the metadata file like `NamespaceRegistry` depending on if I'm deploying to a sandbox.

However, we have several managed packages installed which may add fields to notable objects, and Salesforce adds new fields with each release.  How can I deal with these?  Can I keep my unit test functional and passing?

Comment: related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/222561/field-level-security-for-new-fields

Comment: closely related, but from the ISV's perspective: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/27744/new-field-permission-during-push-update